# Why Unable to start activity- java.lang.NullPointerException and Unfortunately was stopped app

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

### My logcat

```
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912): Process: com.example.mapexample, PID: 11912
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mapexample/com.example.mapexample.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)

04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at com.example.mapexample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
04-18 12:39:18.789: E/AndroidRuntime(11912):    ... 11 more
```

### Main activity.java code

#### My code was running first, after few days, I was not any changing on code but now code is not working on my device. I get Unfortunately was stopped [App] error on my device

```
package com.example.mapexample;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;


//import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap googleHarita;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (googleHarita == null) {
          googleHarita = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.haritafragment))
                 .getMap();
          if (googleHarita != null) {
                googleHarita.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

                LocationManager locationManager=(LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                Criteria criteria=new Criteria();

                String provider =locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                Location mylocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                double latitude=mylocation.getLatitude();
                double longitude=mylocation.getLongitude();

            LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude); 

                googleHarita.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            googleHarita.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(20));
            googleHarita.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("you hereeee"));

                double mesafe=distFrom(latitude, longitude, 41.021161, 29.004065);
                TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(mesafe));

            }
      }
    }
    public static double distFrom (double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) 
    {

        double earthRadius = 3958.75;
        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);
        double a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2)) *
        Math.sin(dLng/2) * Math.sin(dLng/2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        int meterConversion = 1609;

        return Double.valueOf((double)dist * meterConversion);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

### Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mapexample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <!-- Harita verisini indirebilmek için izinler -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Cihazdan Google Servislerine erişmek için izin -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!-- İndirilenlerin tutulması için izinler -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!--  kullanıcının konumuna erişmek için gerekli izin -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>


    <!-- OpenGL ES 2.0 Google Maps Android API v2 için gerekiyor -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <!-- Google Maps için API anahtarı -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDm24SBhaRLJGc67smkOmUNBys_JNzDuOk" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.mapexample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: What is at line no 40?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that value of the mylocation is coming null.

You should put null validation check on mylocation.

```
if (mylocation != null){
    latitude=mylocation.getLatitude();
    longitude=mylocation.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: My error is gone but mylocation is still null. How to fix that and how to get mylocation

Comment: Please check in settings whether location service in on or off.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
Location mylocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Please note, that `getLastKnownLocation` can return `null`, that is why you get `NPE`. Here is a fix:

```
Location mylocation=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
double latitude;
double longitude;
if (mylocation != null){
    latitude=mylocation.getLatitude();
    longitude=mylocation.getLongitude();
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you for answer. I applied this code and I saw my location is null. But I couldnt understand why mylocation is null

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check the Location manager is enabled or not if not the location will be null.

Try checking

```
 // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

If u facing difficulty [Click Here](http://www.androidsourcehelp.com/2014/03/get-location-and-its-changes-in-android.html)